# R -Markdown for { } curly braces

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm a beginner and trying to generate the `.rmd` solution for a given problem. This is my sample code

```
w <- $\{HHH, TTT, HHT, TTH, HTH, THT, HHT, TTH\}$
w
```

I'm expecting the result as `w = {HHH, TTT, HHT, TTH, HTH, THT, HHT, TTH}`. Can anyone help me to understand this small problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: `$w=\{HHH, TTT, HHT, TTH, HTH, THT, HHT, TTH\}$`